# Plotting a independent variable under a parameter of another variable in R

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have a function

```
    predictshrine<-0*rain-399.8993+5*crops+50.4296*log(citysize)+
    4.5071*wonders*chief+.02301*children*deaths+1.806*children+
   .10799*deaths-2.0755*wonders-.0878*children^2+.001062*children^3-
   .000004288*children^4-.009*deaths^2+.0000530238*deaths^3+
   7.974*sqrt(children)+.026937*wonders^2-.0001305*wonders^3
```

I also have a sequence

```
    children<-seq(0,100,length=500)
```

And a for loop

```
    for(deaths in c(0,5,10,50,100,200))
```

Now what i want to do is be able to plot predictshrine vs children when deaths equals certain amounts and display those graphs all at once with the par(mfrow) function

I have

```
    plot(predictshrine, children)
```

I want to be able to do this function when death=0, when death=10, when death=50 etc.

That way I could have 6 different graphs showing the change in the regression

Ideally i could do something like

```
    plot(predictshrine, children, when deaths = 10 & 20 & 50)
```

but that won't work as code.

I want to incorporate my 4 loop into the equation.

Just to make it clear, deaths and children are  two variables in my multivariable equation

Thanks in advance

-Max

Comment: But what about all the over variables in the regression? eg "wonder" and "crops". Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to iterate over several arguments.  Keep in mind that you need to define all the other variables if you want to do this.  Also, this isn't the most memory-efficient way, but it should work for smaller sizes of combinations.

```
predictshrine<- function(rain,citysize,wonders,chief,children,deaths,crops) {
    0*rain-399.8993+5*crops+50.4296*log(citysize)+
    4.5071*wonders*chief+.02301*children*deaths+1.806*children+
    .10799*deaths-2.0755*wonders-.0878*children^2+.001062*children^3-
    .000004288*children^4-.009*deaths^2+.0000530238*deaths^3+
    7.974*sqrt(children)+.026937*wonders^2-.0001305*wonders^3
}

deathlist = c(0,5,10,50,100,200)
#note that the children value is recycled
res = mapply(predictshrine,children = 1:100,deaths = 
 rep(deathlist,each = 100),
 rain = 0.1, wonders = 1, chief = 1, crops = 0.5,citysize = 1000)
```

Then you can plot this six times.

```
#allow six plots on the panel if you want
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
#loop through different plots
for (i in 1:6)
    plot(1:100,res[1:100 + (i-1)*100])
```

This is what it looks like

[image]